# Issue with file upload source in PHP

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I am creating an upload file page in which I would like user to upload a csv or a zip file.  The code below will only deal with small files (around 10-30kb!), but in the php.ini file it says that the resource limit is above 128m and the *upload_max_filesize* is 64m.  Here is the code so far:

```
<?php
$target_path = "theTargetPath";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

It wont upload any .csv or files over 10-30kb, any assistance or help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any errors? Messages? Some form of information? Because this is so broad, might be because it doesn't like purple.

Comment: I would like the user to be able to upload a max file size of 20mb, or close to it.

Comment: Is there any limit set on your upload form?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would try next:

In your php.ini file, look for these values to set:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Add the below to your .htaccess file:

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
 php_value post_max_size 64M
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, the max file size and post max are 128m and 64m by default.  I could not find the .htaccess file so I created my own and added the second code snippet, but I then had Internal server error 500, but when i deleted the htaccess file it goes back to normal.  Im with Hostpapa btw :\

Comment: You can try increasing the PHP memory limit (https://www.drupal.org/node/29268)  Please upvote as a way to say thanks.

Comment: To get around the internal server error, can you go up a directory and get the root .htaccess file?  Copy that one into your directory and then add the php_values

Comment: Unfortunately there is no .htaccess file in the root (I also checked 'show hidden files and folders'), so I created a new .htaccess and added the php values but it's showing the same error

Comment: Shouldn't `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']` be changed to `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` ?

Comment: nope, you want the file in the `/tmp` dir :)

Comment: Good luck!  I hope you resolve it.

Comment: I know this new question should be on another thread, but could anyone recommend a hosting provider that has a good rep that lets me upload files bigger than dust mites?

Comment: I can recommend WebHostingBuzz.com if you upvote everything of mine :)